# Error "Value error of : Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1." Python, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function and a for loop I am using to split a column into 5 around '.'. This was working on the first run but now it is spitting out a value error of : Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1.

The specific line it has an issue with is:

```
----> 6     data["Keyword"+str(i+1)] = remove_id(i)
```

I am a little stumped. As far as I can tell the code is creating a new column called Keyword1,2,3,4,5 and adding in the data form each split.

```
new = data["keywords"].str.split(",", n = 6,expand = True)
def remove_id(i):
    return new[i].str.split(".", n=1, expand = True)
    
for i in range(5):
    data["Keyword"+str(i+1)] = remove_id(i)
    
data.head()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Update, details on data:
[image: Selection of data, includes keywords column before processing]

Here is the 'new' data frame created to house the keywords after they are split:
[image]

Comment: Can you add an example of your data ?. You can refer: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: can you provide an example of how the keyword column looks like

Comment: Have added in some data examples